# Rails - switching my rails app DB from sqlite3 to postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, windows, postgresql

I've create a RoR application with default database sqlite3. but the problem is sqlite3 is supported on heroku (deploying my app on cloud).

It's been whole day but i can't be able to connect my rails app to postgresql.
This is the steps I've followed till now to connect my app to postgresql

```
Replace: gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
with: gem 'pg'

then: bundle install
```

successfully install all the gems

after that convert my db to postgresql

```
conflict  config/database.yml
Overwrite D:/New folder/amazon-product/config/database.yml? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdhm] 
       force  config/database.yml
        gsub  Gemfile
        gsub  Gemfile
```

in that it's overwrite my existing database.yml file to postgresql

after that when i enter command

```
rake db:create db:migrate
```

it giving me the error

```
rails db:create db:migrate
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'pg'.
Gem Load Error is: AddDllDirectory failed for C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/x64-mingw32Backtrace for gem load error is:
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/ruby_installer/runtime/dll_directory.rb:83:in `add_dll_directory_winapi'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/ruby_installer/runtime/dll_directory.rb:50:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/ruby_installer/runtime/singleton.rb:12:in `new'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/ruby_installer/runtime/singleton.rb:12:in `add_dll_directory'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:15:in `block in <main>'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:26:in `rescue in <main>'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:100:in `register'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'        
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler.rb:175:in `require'
D:/New folder/amazon-product/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
D:/New folder/amazon-product/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
D:/New folder/amazon-product/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:710:in `raw_load_rakefile'        
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'   
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/rake:25:in `load'
C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/rake:25:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
D:/New folder/amazon-product/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
D:/New folder/amazon-product/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
D:/New folder/amazon-product/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
RubyInstaller::Runtime::DllDirectory::WinApiError: AddDllDirectory failed for C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/x64-mingw32
D:/New folder/amazon-product/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
D:/New folder/amazon-product/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
D:/New folder/amazon-product/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
LoadError: 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg_ext.so
D:/New folder/amazon-product/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
D:/New folder/amazon-product/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
D:/New folder/amazon-product/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

my database.yml

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 9.3 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On macOS with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On macOS with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: amazon_product_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user running Rails.
  #username: amazon_product

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  #password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: amazon_product_test

# As with config/credentials.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password or a full connection URL as an environment
# variable when you boot the app. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# If the connection URL is provided in the special DATABASE_URL environment
# variable, Rails will automatically merge its configuration values on top of
# the values provided in this file. Alternatively, you can specify a connection
# URL environment variable explicitly:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['MY_APP_DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
# Read https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full overview on how database connection configuration can be specified.
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: amazon_product_production
  username: amazon_product
  password: <%= ENV['AMAZON_PRODUCT_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

I've already installed postgresql also create a new database table called 'details'
hierarchy of pgadmin 4

```
server --> postgresql 14 --> databases(2) --> postgres, details(which i want to use)
```

Comment: for those looking for ans... I've Found this video helpful
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kVtmnZNC8w

for migrate the heroku DB...go to heroku console from heroku dashboard and run rake db:migrate